# How do you crop an image to be circular with pillow in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, discord.py, image-manipulation

so I'm trying to make a "wanted" command where my bot places the user's avatar image over a wanted poster. I was able to get the command to work but I'm having some trouble trying to crop their avatar to be circular. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['Wanted'])
async def wanted(ctx,*, user: discord.Member = None):
  async with ctx.typing():
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    wanted = Image.open("wanted.png")
    
    asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)

    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)
    bigsize = (asset.size[0] * 3, asset.size[1] * 3)
    mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
    mask = mask.resize(asset.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    asset.putalpha(mask)

    pfp = pfp.resize((682,682))
    output = ImageOps.fit(asset, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))

    output.putalpha(mask)
    
    wanted.paste(pfp,(280,480))

    wanted.save("profile.png")

    await ctx.send(file=discord.File("profile.png"))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'size'```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining because a Discord `Asset` object does not have the attribute `size` [according to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Asset).

What you want to use instead is the [PIL Image object](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) which has the `size` attribute you are looking for.  This can be done by slightly changing your  code:

```py
asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)

data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
pfp = Image.open(data)
# Instead of using asset.size, we use pfp.size.  pfp is a PIL Image object
# that has the size attribute.
bigsize = (pfp.size[0] * 3, pfp.size[1] * 3)
```